# How to share global variable across the files in python?

Tags: python, variables, module

I am trying to find a way to share a variable between multiple python scripts. I have the following code:

**b.py**

```
my_variable = []
```

**a.py**

```
from b import my_variable  # import the value
def run():
       global x
       x = my_variable.append("and another string")
       print(my_variable)
if __name__ == '__main__':
       run()
```

**c.py**

```
import a
print(a.x)
```

**a.py** runs just fine without giving any error. However, when I run the **c.py** file, it gives off the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/MOmarFarooq/Programming/Projects/Python Projects/Variables across files/c.py", line 2, in 
<module>
print(a.x)
AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'x'
```

What I want the code to do is, print the new value of **my_variable** *after it has been changed in a.py*  . Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

the error occurred because you never called the run function from a.py. The `if __name__=='__main__':` statement is only satisfied if you are running a.py as a program, not importing it as a module.
So a.py should be

```
from b import my_variable  # import the value
def run():
       global x
       x = my_variable.append("and another string")
       print(my_variable)
run()
```

Note that x will be set to `None` because the append function does not return anything. It just appends a value to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, module 'a' ***does*** have no attribute 'x'. Module 'a' has a function that creates a variable 'x', but as long as the method isn't called, the attribute isn't there.

You could change file `c.py` to:

```py
import a
a.run()
print(a.x)
```

Another solution would be to make sure that the `run()` function is always called when importing module 'a'. This is currently not the case, because of the line `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

If you don't want to run the code but only want to make sure the variable exists, just define it in the module. Before the definition of your `run()` method, just add `x = None` (or use any other initial value you prefer).

Note, however, that there other problems with your code and that using globals in this way is a really bad programming pattern, which will likely lead to other problems later on. I wonder what you want to achieve. It probably would be a better solution if you could pass `x` as argument to the `run()` function instead of referring to a global variable. But that's outside the scope of this question and difficult to answer without more information.

Comment: But this runs the whole a.py script. I don't want that to happen. I just want to import the x variable and use it c.py. Is there any way to make that happen? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @OmarFarooq, did this answer your question? If so, consider upvoting it and marking it as accepted. If not, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `run()` function in your c.py file.
Here's how the code should be:

```
import a
a.run()
```

Comment: But this runs the whole a.py script. I don't want that to happen. I just want to import the x variable and use it c.py. Is there any way to make that happen? Thank you for your time.